# How can I calculate times with gps data using random points on the track?

Tags: qgis, gps

I have GPS data from a car that is circulating all the time in a closed circuit. I need to put a few points along the route, about 3 or 4 and calculate the time it takes to get between points. These points would be 3 or 4 points, no more. And also for the whole lap time.

How can I calculate the time between those points at random positions and the calculated time to make a full lap?  Maybe I need to use Excel for example?

Someone recommended me to create a Network with circuit lines that follow as a road network. But I really do not understand the concept.

Comment: I think it would help if you could include a picture of what you are trying to describe.